# Struggling with mapred.cluster.map.memory.mb and mapred.job.map.memory.mb

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm

Recently, I am exploring the task memory limits of Hadoop. Here's some summary and confusing points I proposed; hope someone could correct me if I am wrong and give me clues about the confusing points.

1. ([as this post mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027817/different-ways-of-configuring-the-memory-to-the-tasktracker-child-process-mappe))mapred.child.java.opts and mapred.job.map.memory.mb are different memory usage aspects. mapred.child.java.opts just gives the maximum heap size which child JVM can use; mapred.job.map.memory.mb is maximum virtual memory allowed by a Hadoop task subprocess and can be larger than maprechild.java.opts because it also need store other memory stuff(stack, etc) except heap.
2. somtimes setting mapred.child.java.opts is not enough for these reasons: a. this property only consider heap size for each JVM, so it would not flexible(eg. if my mapper task wants more memory but my reducer only need a little memory); b. this property doesn't consider the situation of spawning new process from original task which are not constrained in their total memory, this situation may bring a huge memory usage affect for whole task process tree.
3. Hadoop gives us two choices for above disadvantages: one is by setting mapred.child.ulimit. This property which is strict upper bound could prevent single JVM process from leaking memory and affecting other running processes. But, this property also is not flexible and does't consider the spawned processes.
4. another choice is by setting mapred.cluster.map.memory.mb (The size, in terms of virtual memory, of a `single map slot` in the Map-Reduce framework, used by the scheduler. `A job can ask for multiple slots for a single map task` via mapred.job.map.memory.mb, up to the limit specified by mapred.cluster.max.map.memory.mb) and setting mapre.job.map.memory.mb (The size, in terms of virtual memory, of a single map task for the job. if this map task use more memory than this property, this task will be terminated).

The choice 4 is better so far for Hadoop-0.x, However, I have some questions about this choice: the book says this choice could enforces the whole task process tree, including spawned process. Could anyone know some more details about this choice why it also can limit the spawned process?

Comment: struggling with the same thing. Figure anything out?