# Hadoop memory limit exceeded

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a Hadoop streaming job. This job fails with error:

```
"TaskTree [pid=13549,tipID=attempt_201202130706_121058_m_000000_0] is running beyond memory-limits. Current usage : 1667149824bytes. Limit : 1610612736bytes. Killing task."
```

For this job, mapred.job.map.memory.mb is set to 1536. Setting this to `1536*2 = 3072` helps, but causes 1 map task to use 2 slots which is not desirable.

When I ran this job on host, I found that it uses peak memory of 1.07 GB which is way less than 1536 MB. I verified memory usage of job on host using "top" and a script which uses `"ps -o vsz=${pid}"` at every 1 second.

Can somebody please help me to understand/debug/fix this problem.

Comment: Looks like YARN, which Hadoop version are you using?

Comment: $ hadoop version
Hadoop 0.20.205.0.3.1112071329
...

Comment: sunillp, check this from stackoverflow, [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017500/specifying-memory-limits-with-hadoop

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be related with this bug I found on CDH version [here](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.0/bk_releasenotes_hdp_1.x/content/ch_relnotes-hdp1.3.0_5_hive.html):

> MapReduce task from Hive dynamic partitioning query is killed.
>
> Problem: When using the Hive script to create and populate the partitioned table dynamically, the following error is reported in the TaskTracker log file:

```
TaskTree [pid=30275,tipID=attempt_201305041854_0350_m_000000_0] is running beyond memory-limits. Current usage : 1619562496bytes. Limit : 1610612736bytes. Killing task.
```

You have to switch off the memory settings in *mapred-site.xml*:

```
mapred.cluster.map.memory.mb = -1
mapred.cluster.reduce.memory.mb = -1
mapred.job.map.memory.mb = -1
mapred.job.reduce.memory.mb = -1
mapred.cluster.max.map.memory.mb = -1
mapred.cluster.max.reduce.memory.mb = -1
```