# Hadoop map step returns to big dataset

Tags: hadoop

Have a theoretical question: I am processing 100G text files. My map step will return many key-value pairs. What if size of the data set does not fit into memory?

what will happen? and how to handle such use case?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

Your key-value pairs won't be stored in memory. They are written to temporary files on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Your output key-values generated over File System rather in MEMORY, so it'll continue

Answer (score 0):

If this was an actual issue hadoop would be crippled. Data is stored in the Reducer Nodes local directory. Hadoop by design is meant to take on big data problems 100G text files are nothing. Hadoop is ready to take terabytes of data and run jobs on it.

But if you are running out of virtual memory in your actual method calls(like for some reason you trying to load 100g into a data structure), then you could theoretically configure the virtual memory for your reducers.

Not best example but I found this quickly
[Specifying memory limits with hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017500/specifying-memory-limits-with-hadoop)

So if each node has 16gigs of ram, you could turn that puppy up to 8gig. Which if it is still not enough then you have to work on your code to use less memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is been generated on the File system of your Hadoop cluster not in the memory. 100g is not to worried about that Hadoop is capable to process terabytes of data. Yes one more its matter that where you configure your cluster on distributed systems or on virtual.